# Convert bytestring to array of uint8 Python

Tags: numpy, performance, multidimensional-array, cryptography, sha

I was wondering what the fastest way of converting a bytestring to an array of unit8 would be in the following code? I use hashlib for SHA-256

```
x = hashlib.sha256(str(word).encode("ascii")).digest()
```

Now I need to convert x to an array of uint8. I currently do this by list comprehension, but this seems slow.

```
h_new = [int(y) for y in x]
num_hashes[idx_perm, :] = h_new
```

Does anyone have suggestions for a faster way of conversion?

Comment: `list(b'123')` is an example, but python doesn't have a uint8 type whereas numpy does. So which do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the function **`frombuffer`** of Numpy. Since the size of a sha256 is always 32 bytes and the output type is well known, the function can convert the input buffer `x` very quickly.

```py
num_hashes[idx_perm, :] = np.frombuffer(x, np.uint8, 32)
```

This takes about 0.7 us per call on my machine while the initial code takes about 3.35 us. Thus, this version is about **4.8  faster**. Note that this is also faster than converting the result to a list (due to the many int objects to be allocated and reference-counted) and the from `fromiter` Numpy function (since the iterable interface introduces an additional overhead).